# How to use Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel (Excel instance) twice in the same controller

Tags: php, excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I'm trying to read excel sheet before importing data to implement some logic like this

```
if(count($imagesNames) > 0) {
            $collection = Excel::toCollection(
                new UserImport,
                public_path('uploads/' . $usersFileName)
            );

            $excelImagesNames = $collection[0]->pluck('image')->toArray();
            $diffArray = array_diff($imagesNames,$excelImagesNames);
            if(count($diffArray) > 0){
                return $this->response->error('Uploaded images and user images in excel file are not the same.', null,
                    400);
            }
        }

        Excel::import(
            new UsersImport(
                $entity,
                $user,
                $request->get('unique_fields'),
                $request->get('update_duplicates'),
                new JobHistory,
            ),
            public_path('uploads/'.$usersFileName),
            null,
            \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::XLSX
        );
```

UserImport

```
class UserImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{
  public function model(array $row)
  {
      return new User(array_map(function($v) {
          return str_replace("'", '', $v);
      }, $row));
  }
}
```

UsersImport which contains the whole import logic (this is just part of it)

```
class UsersImport implements ToCollection, WithValidation, WithHeadingRow, WithChunkReading, ShouldQueue, WithEvents
{
private $entity, $user, $updateDuplicates, $uniqueFields, $jobHistory;

public function __construct(Entity $entity, User $user, array
$uniqueFields, string $updateDuplicates, JobHistory $jobHistory)
{
    $this->entity = $entity;
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->updateDuplicates = $updateDuplicates;
    $this->uniqueFields = $uniqueFields;
    $this->jobHistory = $jobHistory;
}

public function collection(Collection $rows)
{
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $data = $row->toArray();
        array_walk($data, array($this, 'parseData'));

        if ($this->updateDuplicates !== null) {

            $user = User::uniqueFields($this->uniqueFields, $data);

            if ($user->count() > 0 && $this->updateDuplicates) {
                $user->update($data);
                continue;
            } elseif (!$this->updateDuplicates) {
                continue;
            }
        }

        User::create($data);
    }
}
```

So if the user uploads a folder for images it'll start checking if the image columns contains same names of images in the extracted images folder. If everything is OK it'll start importing the excel file and inserting data into the database but I get

```
serialize(): &quot;spreadsheet&quot; returned as member variable from __sleep() but does not exist
```

If I remove the `Excel::import` code, the error isn't displaying but sure it won't import data and if I keep this import logic and remove the `Collection` part, the import works fine so I guess it can't run 2 queues after each other like this if I'm correct. Why does this error show up and how to fix it according to my logic?

Comment: PHP classes have a magic method called `__sleep()` that is run when the object is serialized. It specifies which properties are to be included in the serialization. It's returning `spreadsheet` as one of the properties to serialize, but the object you're trying to serialize doesn't have it.

Comment: The error message you've partly quoted includes the location of the code that triggered the error and the stack trace leading to it. Using that information you should be able to find where in your code the problem lies.